# PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground ERROR with UIImage()

Tags: ios, json, swift, parse-platform

I want to save an image from an UIImage as a PFFile. But then I got the error :

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

As you will see in the snippet I print the data of the image and I got something in it.
If I comment the setting of the image to the current user everything is working fine (w/o the image obviously).

Any idea where to look ?

```
@IBAction func updateProfil(_ sender: Any) {
        PFUser.current()!["isFemale"] = genderSwitch.isOn

        if let image = profilImage.image {
            print(image)
            if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                print(data)
                PFUser.current()!["image"] = PFFile(name: "profile.png", data: data)
                PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground(block: { (s, e) in
                    if e != nil {
                        print(e as Any)
                        self.getErrorFromServer(errServeur: e, errMessage: "Update Failed")
                    } else {
                        self.showSuccessMessage(m: "Info uploaded")
                        print("Data Saved !")

                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "updatedProfile", sender: nil)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

`print(image)` and `print(data)` give me respectively :

```
<UIImage: 0x6080000a8580> size {1200, 704} orientation 0 scale 1.000000
1411255 bytes
```

Comment: Which line causes the error -- creating the file or saving the user?

Comment: I dig deeper and it's seem that if I pick a pic (from the library using imagePickerController) and putting it in an UIImage with an image already in the PNG format everything is doing ok. But if it's a JPEG it failed.

I thought that `UIImagePNGRepresentation` would convert an UIImage data to PNG what ever is the source ?

Comment: How you installed your parse-server instance? are you using nginx or some reverse proxy?

Comment: Plain AWS image with MongoDB on a MLab free instance

Comment: I think thats related to the max limit. Can you please try to replace the UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) with 
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)
        let f = PFFile(name: "image.jpg", data: data, contentType: "image/jpeg")
and try again?

Comment: I put that handmade file named f inside my object right ?
I see what you are trying to make me do. I try.

Comment: for your PFile I got an error `Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`

Comment: So replace the PFFile creation with this one: PFFile(data: data, contentType: "image/jpeg") because this one not throws anything (just for testing)

Comment: Yep it's working.
So what is the limitation you are talking about ?

Comment: How I see the 0.1 in UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1) is for compression ? My image was too big right ?

Comment: I will provide it in the answer (because you have control on it) so read it in 2 mins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this happened due to the size of your file. One of parse-server configuration options is **maxUploadSize**. The default value of it is 20MB means that you will not be able to upload files larger than 20MB. You can override this value in your parse-server configuration to 100MB (unless you are dealing with really big files like: videos etc.)

I think the best solution for you will also be to **compress** the image before you uploading it to parse-server. Compressing the image will reduce its size dramatically and will keep its quality (because the JPEG compression) so before uploading the image you need to do the following:

```
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
    let f = PFFile(data: data, contentType: "image/jpeg")
```

the 0.5 is the quality, the max value of it is 1 but if you will set it to 0.5 or even 0.4 you will get a very good result. In addition, you can compress the image by scale it down. This is something that will also reduce its size dramatically but its really depends on your use case.

Increasing the size on the parse-server side should be like the following:

```
var server = ParseServer({
  ...otherOptions,
  // Set the max upload size of files
  maxUploadSize: 100MB,
  ....
});
```

Good luck with it

Comment: Thank you awesome !
But this limitation it is due to mongoDB limit of 16Mb/document ?
If I set, let say 100MB like in you exemple do Parse use GridFS or something else ?

Comment: By default it uses GridFS but I strongly recommend you to use storage service (like Amazon S3 for instance). It's really straight forward and it will make your solution much more scale.